# "Result of method is ignored" - How to resolve this problem

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How can I fix "Result of [function call] is ignored" and "Return value of the method is never used" in the following?

```
public class barkingDog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        barkingDog.shouldWakeUp(true, 1);
    }

    public static boolean shouldWakeUp (boolean barking, int hourOfDay) {
        if (barking && (hourOfDay < 8 || hourOfDay >22)){
            return true;
        }
        else if (!barking && hourOfDay<0 || hourOfDay>23){
            return false;
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Problem1: Result of 'barkingDog.shouldWakeUp()' is ignored

Problem2 : Return value of the method is never used

What does it mean? What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: You are not doing anything with the value that is `return`ed from `shouldWakeUp`. So you are just calling the method and nothing will happen - you won't see anything. You should do something with the value like make a decision based on it or print it.

Comment: It just means that the method `shouldWakeUp` is returning a `boolean`  but you aren't using it. To quiet the error, you can either set a variable to the return type or use the value insome way

Comment: BTW that is most probably just a warning - it *can* be ignored, the program is still executable, but eventually with some bug

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is nothing technically wrong with your code. IntelliJIdea just tries to help you and says that your code might be pointless and not do what you really want. I also do not understand this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    barkingDog.shouldWakeUp(true, 1);
}
```

It looks like you are asking a question and do not care about the answer :) I've slightly changed your code (I also allowed myself to fix the naming according to the Sun convention and remove unnecessary qualified reference):

```
public class BarkingDog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean shouldI = shouldWakeUp(true, 1);
        if (shouldI) {
            System.out.println("Ok, ok. I'm almost wake :))))");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Damn dog, shut up!!!");
        }
    }

    public static boolean shouldWakeUp(boolean barking, int hourOfDay) {
        if (barking && (hourOfDay < 8 || hourOfDay > 22)) {
            return true;
        } else if (!barking && hourOfDay < 0 || hourOfDay > 23) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

See the difference? In my code I'm asking "Should I wake up or not?", then I take the response (the value that method `shouldWakeUp` returned to me) and according to it I behave: in this example, depending on the answer I output different messages to the console.